# How to add objects from an NSDictionary to an NSArray for a UIActionSheet UIButton list

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, uiactionsheet

my dictionary

```
    myDictionary = [[publicDataCityArray valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"myDictionary is %@ myDictionary count is %i",   myDictionary,  [myDictionary count]);
```

`NSLog` output:

```
myDictionary is (
    Roma,
    Milano,
    Rimini,
    Venezia,
    Firenze,
    Napoli,
    Cesenatico,
    Cervia,
    Recco,
    "Abano Terme",
    "Abbadia Cerreto",
    "Abbadia Lariana",
    "Abbadia San Salvatore",
    Abbasanta,
    Abbateggio,
    Abbiategrasso,
    Abetone,
    Abriola,
    Acate,
    Accadia,
    Acceglio,
    Accettura,
    Acciano,
    Accumoli,
    Acerenza,
    Acerno,
    Acerra,
    "Aci Bonaccorsi",
    "Aci Castello",
    "Aci Catena",
    "Aci Sant'Antonio",
    Acireale,
    Acquacanina,
    Acquafondata,
    Acquaformosa,
    Acquafredda,
    Acqualagna,
    "Acquanegra Cremonese",
    "Acquanegra sul Chiese",
    Acquapendente
) myDictionary count is 40
```

and I'm trying to populate the `UIActionSheet` array:

```
-(void) someMethod{

    NSError *requestError = nil;

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"token"];

    NSString *stringWithToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&token=%@",kCityURL, savedValue];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringWithToken]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&requestError];

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"sync. request failed with error: %@", requestError);
    }
    else {
        // handle data
        NSArray *publicDataCityArray =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

        myDictionary = [[publicDataCityArray valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"myDictionary is %@ myDictionary count is %i",   myDictionary,  [myDictionary count]);

        for (NSDictionary *publicCityDataDict in publicCityDataArray) {

            arrayCitiesActionSheet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: myDictionary, @"city5", @"city6", @"city7", @"city8",@"city9", @"city10", @"city11", @"city12", @"city13", @"city14", @"city15", @"city16", nil];


           // arrayCitiesActionSheet = [myDictionary allValues];

        }

    }

    UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];

    actionSheet.title = @"SELECT A CITY";

    actionSheet.delegate = self;

    for(int i=0;i<[myDictionary count];i++)

    {

        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[arrayCitiesActionSheet objectAtIndex:i]];

    }

    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

}
```

Comment: So what exactly does not work? - Btw., `myDictionary` looks like an NSArray to me, not an NSDictionary.

Comment: I was about to say exactly same Martin. Diction logs key value pair not values. Please check your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try with taking `myDictionary` as array,

try this ,

```
 for(int i=0;i<[myDictionary count];i++)
    {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[arrayCitiesActionSheet objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

replace it with

```
for(int i=0;i<[myDictionary count];i++)
        {
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[myDictionary objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
```